# Superconductivity and superfluidity energy dissipation

Tags: thermodynamics, friction, superconductivity, dissipation, superfluidity

All articles say that in superconductive state, the materials have exactly zero resistance, but **is this the case in real life experiment?**, because if this were true, a process without energy dissipation, wouldn't it be contradictory with thermodynamics. Same question with friction for superfluids. Also if either were true could you support it with a scientific article (no Wikipedia if possible).

Comment: The second law says $\dot S\geq 0$. Nothing wrong with the equal sign.

Comment: The equal is when no process happens.

Comment: No, reversible processes, like superfluid flow, have $\dot{S}=0$. Now you can argue that in the real world nothing is ever exactly reversible (the system interacted with a cosmic background photon ..), but there is no limitation in principle. In practice, superconducting currents have been sustained for many years.

Comment: @Thomas The truth is that the entropy indeed grows in a superconductor, with a typical time-scale with value larger than the age of the universe. Unfortunately, this is all what is written in Wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconductivity#Zero_electrical_DC_resistance so the OP will complain. Just one thing though : if user162485 had an eye on wiki's page, (s)he will find references for this standard fact of physics that nothing is eternal !

Comment: @FraSchelle The Wiki entry only says that (i) if the superconductor is type II, and (ii) if there is a large B-field, then there is a new dissipation mechanism (vortex drag). That's fine. This does not change the fact that if you set up a pure superflow in a ring,  there is no dissipation mechanism (it cannot decay by quantization of circulation).

Comment: @Thomas The section [Elementary properties of superconductors -> Zero electrical DC resistance] I cite especially says: *Experiments have demonstrated that currents in superconducting coils can persist for years without any measurable degradation. Experimental evidence points to a current lifetime of at least 100,000 years. Theoretical estimates for the lifetime of a persistent current can exceed the estimated lifetime of the universe, depending on the wire geometry and the temperature.* And then cite John C. Gallop (1990) SQUIDS, the Josephson Effects and Superconducting Electronics-CRC Press

Comment: @Thomas A simple way to let the current decaying is to increase the temperature so as to pass the transition temperature. The quantisation argument is valid only at zero temperature, where in any case the entropy flow is indeed zero, am I correct ?

Comment: @FraSchelle: The quantization argument is valid at $T<T_c$. If the superconductor/superfluid is coupled to a heat bath, then you can of course wait for a thermal fluctuation that will push the superflow above $T_c$. But a superflow is a mcaroscopically occupied state, so you have to wait for some time $O(e^{10^{23}})$ (not any time soon). In the mean time $\dot S=0$ exactly.

Comment: There is a subtlety: A finite T superconductor/superfluid (in thermal equilibrium) is a mixture of a normal fluid (not quantized) and a superfluid (quantized). In practice the normal flow quickly decays, and your left with pure superflow. This is, strictly speaking, not an equilibrium state, but it cannot decay to an equilibrium state without tunneling through a very high barrier, so the lifetime is infinite in practice.

Comment: @Thomas If we agree, why do we have polemics ?